# Can a renderPlot output be delayed for a few seconds till all reactive subsets are calculated?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to make a dashboard on Shiny that displays a reactive radar chart.

For my inputs the user first selects one team from a list of teams. Then the next drop down menu will update the list of players based on the team selected.

Once the user selects a player as well, a subset of his attributes from the data set is taken and a radar chart of his attributes is displayed.

The chart displays smoothly for any player from the same team. However, when I select another team, there is like a one second period where the list of players still has the list of the old team before it is updated.

In that ensuing period, since there is a team and player mismatch, there is no data in the subset. Hence I get an error message, but immediately after the calculation is complete, the correct plot is displayed. So how can I add a delay of a second or two before the plot is displayed?

```
#Select team  
output$t <- renderUI({ 
    selectInput(inputId = "x", choices = as.character(unique(d$team)))
  })

#Select player
output$p <- renderUI({
    d1 = d[d$team == input$x, "player"]
    selectInput(inputId = "y", choices = unique(d1))
    })

#Plot
output$r <- renderPlot({
    rating <- (subset(x = d, d$team == input$x & d$player == input$y))[,c("F1","F2")]
    radarchart(df = rating)
})
```

Comment: Try adding `shiny::validate(need(input$x, F), need(input$y, F))` as the first line under `renderPlot({ ... })`. This requires both input values to be truthy before the chart is rendered.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I tried validate but I still see the error message - "[Data not enough at 3] NA". This is happening when there is a team-player mismatch as player list is getting updated on selection of a new team.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code that I modified below with the `req()` function.

```
#Select team  
output$t <- renderUI({ 
    selectInput(inputId = "x", choices = as.character(unique(d$team)))
  })

#Select player
output$p <- renderUI({
    d1 = d[d$team == input$x, "player"]
    selectInput(inputId = "y", choices = unique(d1))
    })

#Plot
output$r <- renderPlot({
    rating <- (subset(x = d, d$team == input$x & d$player == input$y))[,c("F1","F2")]
    req(nrow(rating) > 0)  # Only proceed to the next line if rating is not empty
    radarchart(df = rating)
})
```